# Filter, join and modify two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a project in Typescript in which I want to join two arrays taking into account the information of a field, that is, if the value of that field matches, delete one and merge the data of that array.

These are my `arrays`:

```
let sheet = [ { fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1 },
{ fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1 } ]
    
let ftp = [ { fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0 },
{ fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_PRU.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0 } ]
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
let result = [ { fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 1 },
{ fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1 },
{ fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_PRU.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0 } ]
```

This is the code I have so far, at the moment I only manage to filter the data that is not in the other array:

```
let onlyFtp = ftp.filter(await this.objectComparer(sheet, ftp, 'fileName'));
let onlySheet = sheet.filter(await this.objectComparer(ftp, sheet, 'fileName'));

public async objectComparer(fstArr: any, secArr: any) {
    try {

        let only = fstArr.filter(
          (fstItem: any) => !secArr.some((secItem: any) => fstItem[key] === secItem[key])
        );
        
        return only;
      
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }  
}

onlyFtp = [{ fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_PRU.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0 } ]
    
onlySheet = [{ fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1 } ]
```

With this I get the arrays that do not change, so I would only have to update the array where the filename is 'CO_SER.txt'

**My problem**: I need to remove the arrays repeated by the fileName field, but I don't know how to merge both arrays and change the corresponding property

Comment: Show us your coding attempt.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have updated my code with what I have now, I only manage to filter those that do not match to know those that do not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat both arrays and Merge using for loop -

```js
const date = '12/07/2021';
const sheet = [{
    fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1
  },
  {
    fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1
  }
];

const ftp = [{
    fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0
  },
  {
    fecDate: date,
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_PRU.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0
  }
];

const merged = [...sheet, ...ftp];
const result = [];
for (const item of merged) {
  const existingItem = result.find(f => f.fileName == item.fileName);
  if (!existingItem) {
    result.push(item);
  } else {
    existingItem.ftpExists |= item.ftpExists;
    existingItem.sheetExists |= item.sheetExists;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With usage of map (unique keys)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

```js
let sheet = [ { fecDate: '',
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1 },
{ fecDate: '',
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_DAT.txt',
    ftpExists: 0,
    sheetExists: 1 } ]
    
let ftp = [ { fecDate: '',
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_SER.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0 },
{ fecDate: '',
    codCountry: 'CO',
    fileName: 'CO_PRU.txt',
    ftpExists: 1,
    sheetExists: 0 } ]
    
const map = new Map([...sheet, ...ftp].map(i => [i.fileName, i]))

// assuming sheets array sets sheetExists property
sheet.forEach(item => {
  // map.get(item.fileName).sheetExists = 1
  // edit:
  const mapItem = map.get(item.fileName)
  mapItem.ftpExists = mapItem.ftpExists || item.ftpExists
  mapItem.sheetExists = mapItem.sheetExists || item.sheetExists
})

const result = Array.from(map.values())
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is only valid for this case, but if the field to modify is ftpExists then you have to change the code

Comment: that is what code comment above forEach says

Comment: code updated, i was assuming that one array defines sheets and the second ftps, so sheets array cannot set ftpExists value